# Bootstrap input group 1px diference

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use input-group in modal dialog. And the button is 1px less then other elements. How can I fix it, more then less why I have this bug? I use Bootstrap 3

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="buttons input-group col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-9">
    <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">ks</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-remove color-red"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, the bug was because of a rounding error.

there's this style rule

```
.btn {
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

which should be

```
.btn {
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
```

Turns out importing bootstrap within other SASS files resulted in a loss of precision. The SASS compile process needed the flag `--precision 8` to work correctly.

For you, though, as noted in another answer, you just need to put your icon in another tag.

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-red">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Perfectly answered for me

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this today, and with a bit of googling and experimentation, it seems the correct way to use a glyphicon is to always use the icon class on it's own span, and not to combine it with other classes / components.

If your example; you would do the following:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-red">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
</span>
```

With this there is no need to to any style changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by using a glyphicon on the button, and seems to be a bug with bootstrap. Use

```
 .input-group-btn>.glyphicon {margin-top: -1px;}
```

to fix it.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/85m5mwsg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove top of `.glyphicon`

http://jsbin.com/dufisukefe/3/edit

```
.input-group-btn .glyphicon
{
top :0px
}
```